# Intellisense in SAS

Tags: sas, intellisense

Is there an option to enable IntelliSense in PROC SQL SAS enterprise guide?eg. Autofil Table names, Columns etc. Also highlights errors in code like missing ; etc.

Thank you

Comment: You can turn on autocomplete in the preferences window, and I remember there is an system option to check missing `;`, it may need you to submit code first.

Comment: We are working on an open source linter to pick up coding errors.  You can download it in VS Code by searching for "sasjs", or `npm i -g @sasjs/cli` and run `sasjs lint`.

https://github.com/sasjs